# Command line args with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, spaces

Invoking a shell script with command line arguments containing spaces is generally solved by enclosing the argument in quotes:

```
getParams.sh 'one two' 'foo bar'
```

Produces:

```
one two
foo bar
```

getParams.sh:

```
while [[ $# > 0 ]]
do
    echo $1
    shift
done
```

However, if a shell variable is first defined to hold the value of the arguments such as:

```
args="'one two' 'foo bar'"
```

then why does:

```
getParams.sh $args
```

not recognize the single quotes enclosing the grouped arguments? The output is:

```
'one
two'
'three
four'
```

How can I store command line arguments containing spaces into a variable so that when getParams is invoked, the arguments are grouped according to the quoted arguments just as in the original example?

Comment: The shell parses quotes (and escapes and a bunch of other things) before expanding variables, so putting quotes in variables isn't the same as using them directly on the command line. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `[[ $# > 0 ]]` does a string comparison.  `[[ $# -gt 0 ]]` or `(( $# > 0 ))` or even `while (($#))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array:

```
args=('one two' 'foo bar')

getParams.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Using `args="'one two' 'foo bar'"` wont work, because the single quotes retain their literal value when inside double quotes.

To preserve multiple spaces in the arguments (and also handle special characters such as `*`), you should quote your variable:

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

Comment: Thank you, @user000001. That mostly works. The remaining problem is that multiple spaces are replaced with one space. How do I preserve all the spaces if some strings have multiple adjacent spaces embedded?

Comment: @tgoneil: You should quote the variable (`"$1"`) to preserve multiple whitespaces in echo.

Comment: Ah ha! That did the trick! Thank you @user000001!