Why is dash quoting different in script and interactive?
I hope I have not fallen victim to the intricacies of shell expansion, but to me it seems dash treats quoting different depending on whether it's on an interactive command line, or in a script.
I have been trying to auto-start mjpeg-streamer, and worked out a script that would invoke start-stop-daemon. mjpeg-streamer has the peculiarity that it requires some options to contain whitespace, hence quoting is required. I supplied -x to the script's shebang line, and I could see the call to start-stop-daemon having options quoted correctly. But mjpeg-streamer wouldn't run. It would however, if the same line is pasted to the interactive command line. I'm sure I could work around this, but I'd like to understand and learn.
Trying to get to the bottom of the puzzle, I wrote three scripts, massively simplifying in order to isolate the issue. The first one replaces mjpeg-streamer, just showing the options it received:
$ cat to_be_daemon
#!/bin/sh
echo "num=$#"
while [ -n "$1" ];
  do
     echo "opt: $1"
     shift
  done
exit 0

The second would mimic start-stop-daemon in calling the other script:
$ cat ssd_mimic 
#!/bin/sh
exe="$1"
shift
${exe} "$@"
exit 0

The third one is a cut-down version of the initial work:
$ cat starter
#!/bin/sh -x
exe="/tmp/to_be_daemon"
input="input -r 1920x1080 -f 30"
output="output -n -p 8080"
options="-i '${input}' -o '${output}'"
/tmp/ssd_mimic ${exe} -- ${options}
exit 0

Notice how in the second to last line the call to start-stop-daemon is imitated. If I run the last script, I get
$ ./starter
+ exe=/tmp/to_be_daemon
+ input=input -r 1920x1080 -f 30
+ output=output -n -p 8080
+ options=-i 'input -r 1920x1080 -f 30' -o 'output -n -p 8080'
+ /tmp/ssd_mimic /tmp/to_be_daemon -- -i 'input -r 1920x1080 -f 30' -o 'output -n -p 8080'
num=12
opt: --
opt: -i
opt: 'input
opt: -r
opt: 1920x1080
opt: -f
opt: 30'
opt: -o
opt: 'output
opt: -n
opt: -p
opt: 8080'
+ exit 0

Note how in the call to ssd_mimic the quotes are exactly where they are supposed to be, but the following output clearly shows the quotes do not quote, but are treated like any other character! If I run exactly that call on an interactive command line, the behaviour is different, and as intended:
$ /tmp/ssd_mimic /tmp/to_be_daemon -- -i 'input -r 1920x1080 -f 30' -o 'output -n -p 8080'
num=5
opt: --
opt: -i
opt: input -r 1920x1080 -f 30
opt: -o
opt: output -n -p 8080

Why is that?
PS.: I have tried to use bash, but that is even worse, I even have trouble getting the quoting right in the first place. Bash inserts additional quotes in some weird way, as has already been remarked in the highest scoring answer to the question start-stop-daemon quoted arguments misinterpreted.
PPS.: The dash is version 0.5.10.2-5 from Devuan Chimera, which corresponds to Debian Bulleye.

The underlying problem is that you aren't using arrays (or, with more work printf %q followed by eval, or equivalent). Your misunderstanding is because unquoted expansion does not care about quotes inside the string. With dash the only array that's accessible is the arguments, set -- arg1 arg2 arg3; bash supports proper arrays.

bash shows in -x the quotes that would be used/needed on INPUT, but no POSIX shell, including bash or dash, ever interprets quotes in variable expansion. See dupes in my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251421/shell-variable-expansion-storing-multiple-command-arguments-that-include-spaces

the interactive equivalent of your script command is: /tmp/ssd_mimic /tmp/to_be_daemon -- -i \'input -r 1920x1080 -f 30\' -o \'output -n -p 8080\' not what you tried. Consider: var="'"; echo $var

dash does not do quoting different in interactive shell. Create a simple, reproducible example, and demonstrate that you are indeed running it in a interactive dash.
